# Stripe pay method is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have the Ruby gem [Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) for payment processing but cannot seem to make a call to Stripe::Order.pay() method even though it's [in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/orders#create-pay-orders).

```
 > require 'stripe'
 => false
2.3.4 :007 > Stripe::Order.pay()
NoMethodError: undefined method `pay' for Stripe::Order:Class
```

Other functions like `create` work but this one won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of the Stripe gem?

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/427) from a while ago, this may be the case. It was for me and after updating to the latest I was able to call `Stripe::Order.pay` without an issue.

Comment: Can you confirm which version you are using?  I have `stripe (4.19.0, 4.7.0)`

Comment: Seems my local version is off and won't update for a different reason.  I think this fixed it.